# How to populate a database default value when inserting with sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

On my schema, I've this...

```
const userSchema = db.define('USER',
  {
    id: { type: Sequelize.UUIDV4, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
   ...
   }
```

On my MSSQL database, I've this:

```
id uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
```

so, NEWID() will populate the id with a new UUIDV4 data.
However, when I perform a User.create(...), this throw me a ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: USER.id cannot be null

Then I decided to make an attempt:

```
 hooks : {
        beforeCreate(user, options) {
             user.id = generateNewUUID()
        }
     }
```

but it's also not working because hooks is just executed after the schema validation.

is there some work around for this that's not involves placing the id as a parameter of User.create ? It's something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: then remove validations for `id` , as it will always be generated from backend side, so what's the meaning of validation?

Comment: there is no validators on Id

Comment: means remove  `allowNull: false`

Answer (score 1):

Other commenters have observed OP might have been playing with a primary key, which has special behaviour around validation. But the *title* asks about 'values' generally. The common advice on that question is:

1. Remove the `allowNull` requirement on the model definition, or
2. Use a hook to manually insert the default.

These are not great answers. Option 1 is effectively permanently distorting your model (and validations). Option 2 is closer to correct, but still annoying and unintuitive: what's the point in setting a default if I have to build logic to apply it?

For the record: if you did want to go with Option 2, `beforeCreate` will not help (as you have noticed) because that hook is called *after* validation. You would have to use the `beforeValidate` hook-- and then specifically add logic to ensure the hook is only triggered upon the record creation. Like so:

```js
hooks: {
    beforeValidate: async (user) => {
        if (user.isNewRecord) await applyDefaults(user);
    },
}
```

This^ works. But here's the **real** solution:

Don't write any hooks. Define your default value on the model like so:

```js
const userSchema = db.define('USER', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: generateNewUUID()
}})
```

Then, when creating instances, **use Model.build() instead of  Model.create()**. The former applies the defaults properly, before validation. Eg:

```js
var user = User.build({
    email: "myemail@example.com"
})
user = await user.save()
console.log(user.id) // <--- Now works as expected
```

CAVEAT: At time of writing, Sequelize still [doesn't seem to support promises for default values](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4569).  If you need to apply a resolved promise as defaultValue, you're stuck with Options 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `{ allowNull: false }` constraint in order to use a default value from the **DBMS side**.

But if you want to keep the `{ allowNull: false }` constraint, you can alternatively set the default value to  UUIDV4 from the **ORM side** by setting the default value of the column to `Sequelize.UUIDV4` like so:

```
const userSchema = db.define('USER',
  {
    id: {
       type: Sequelize.UUID,
       defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
       allowNull: false,
       primaryKey: true
    },
   ...
   }
```

(you don't need a beforeCreate hook in this case)